# The behavior of dynamically allocated class array

Tags: c++, class, memory-leaks

Assuming if `class A` has some dynamic allocated data array, and `class A` has a user-defined destructor to release the memory allocated by `A` (**RAII** style).

Then if we create a dynamic array of `class A`, lets call it array `B`,  and use the standard `free` function to `free` resource claimed by `B`, can we ensure that each dynamic arrays within `A` has also been properly released?

And what about the situation when there are **nested type** relationship of `B` and `A`? can all the resources of `'A'`s get properly destoried after `'B'`s are freed?

Comment: This question is lacking a massive amount of details.

Comment: `free()` function in C++ will, in 99% cases, create memory leaks. use `delete` or `delete[]`.

Comment: `free` is not the "standard" function in C++ to free memory/resources. The standard function is `delete`. However, if you dynamically allocate an array of a type that has an array in it's `private` section, then you have to call `delete[]` on the array, and the destructor call will do the rest when the function exits.

Answer (score 2):

It all depends how you do it. Here's a perfectly sensible way of using `free`:

```
char * addr = static_cast<char *>(std::malloc(sizeof(A) * 2));

A * p = new (addr) A(100);
A * q = new (addr + sizeof(A)) A(50);

q->~A();
p->~A();

std::free(addr);   // fine
```

This will not leak memory, provided there are no exceptions in the constructor of `A`. As always, you must call `free` precisely on a pointer obtained from `malloc`/`calloc`/`realloc`.

Is this way of writing code insane? Definitely. Don't do it. Use `std::vector<A>` instead.